# JAX RS Client with out any implementation

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, client, jax-rs

I don't want to Jersey, Apache or any other implementation. Is it possible to build client based on javax? 
What will be my dependency list to run on Java EE and where can I download ?

EDIT:
My question is if I can create client purely with javax ? (javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar)  as in here :
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jaxrs-client002.htm#BABJCIJC

If I create the client as mentioned here, I'm getting exception asking for Jersey Classes.

And please point me to the duplicated question if you mark this duplicate. I did my search and couldn't find. thanks,

Comment: You can use any HTTP client library for this task, for example https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html

Comment: I'm not convinced this is necessarily a duplicate

Comment: Can you please provide the link to duplicate question?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is completely unclear. Do you want the JAX-RS API and make an implementation for it on your own based on the specification? Do you want an implementation that you can use based on the JAX-RS API?

Jersey already provides an implementation of the JAX-RS 2.0 API (which is an interface and can be used with any implementation).

Comment: My question is if I can create client purely with javax ? (javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar)  as in here :  https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jaxrs-client002.htm#BABJCIJC    If I create the client as mentioned here, I'm getting exception asking for Jersey Classes.

Comment: No, JavaEE is a set of API specifications that providers have to adhere to. Jersey and Resteasy implement the JAX-RS 2.0 API so they can be interchanged.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JAX-RS 2.0 client APIs with any Java EE 7 server implementation with this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

No other libraries are required, and this jar is only needed at build time.

Java EE implementations include WildFly (formerly JBoss), Apache TomEE, GlassFish, WebSphere and WebLogic.